# How to properly persist in dask dataframe?

Tags: dask

I actually got some weird behavior about persist, I would like to ask shall I use

```
df = client.persist(df)
```

or

```
df = df.persist()
```

Are they the same?

Comment: can you share a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that would help us answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are the same. Perhaps, [documentation](https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manage-computation.html#dask-collections-to-futures) and [source code](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/618aedf8ddc4db71ca19db870421d3be646d9da1/dask/base.py#L222) could help you to investigate your issue further.